# Ubuntu host with ubuntu guest using VMware workstation 12 player, no network connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, vmware

I use a Ubuntu host 14.04 with a ubuntu guest 14.04 using VMware workstation 12 player. The network apdator option is NAT.

However, I am not able to access the internet in the guest VM.

I have another windows 10 host with ubuntu guest 14.04 using VMware workstation 12 player. The network adaptor option is NAT and it works without any problems.

How can I solve the problem in my ubuntu host?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

When executed "ifconfig -a", the output did show an active virtual NIC, but the system could not connect to internet because it didn't have an IP address associated to the NIC (I had given a Bridged network to the guest Ubuntu).

To get it working, edit the file: /etc/network/interfaces

Add these lines:

```
# The primary network interface
auto [vNIC name as appeared on "ifconfig -a" output]
iface [vNIC name] inet dhcp
```

(remove the angular brackets) 
Don't change anything of the loopback interface if you see one.

Save the file and reboot the system. That should do it.